# What is the best cross-browser solution for browser based document signing (w/ digital signature)?

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-certificate, pki

I need to implement a browser based component (most likely java applet since it needs to be cross-browser) that will allow us to digitally sign and verify data in the XadES format. What options are available and what is the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one that seems to work, but is still in development and has some bugs:
http://projectestic.uji.es/pr/cryptoapplet/

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I would think would be to build a web service or if applicable build it right into your application. Unless you want to provide more details on how you plan to implement it or any other platform / business constraints then finding the best solution is a shot in the dark at this point.

So here is how I would start

Google this: **XadES jar library**
 Try a link and then see if it does everything you need.

If it doesn't try the next link and see if that works better.

The best way to ensure it works on all browsers is to perform the work on the server via a web service instead of an applet.